# Get Member for System.DirectoryServices.Protocols and System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory

Tags: powershell

I'm learning Powershell and a beginner. I presume that the following content that I'm executing on Powershell ISE, should yield me the result of different methods & properties, etc.

```
$test_ad_obj = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory

$test_ad_obj | gm

$test_ldp_obj = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.Protocols

$test_ldp_obj | gm

[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory]$adobj1 | gm

[System.DirectoryServices.Protocols]$adobj2 | gm
```

However I keep getting the result,

```
New-Object : Cannot find type [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

```
New-Object : Cannot find type [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

or

```
Unable to find type [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory].
```

```
Unable to find type [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols].
```

Kindly Note that I'm running this on a Windows Server 2019 with the Active Directory Powershell Module installed.

Comment: You're trying to create an object of a [namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectory?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Comment: Did you import the Active Directory module with import-module cmdlet, before executing your content?